# ubuntu 13.10 slow on Asus 1005P

Tags: 13.10, system

After having upgraded from 13.04 which was super stable and performing absolutely o.k. I have great problems with 13.10 now. All graphical processes and programs are extremly slow.
Tried to remove Zeitgeist but failed.
Cab I reinstall 13.04 and how would I do that?
My computer:
Asus 1005P

ram
2 GB

processor
Intel® Atom™ CPU N450 @ 1.66GHz × 2

graphic card
Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)

system
32 Bit

Comment: ASUS products are terrific, any problems you may have, their customer service is good enough to help.
<a href="http://acetecsupport.com/asua_support.html">Asus Technical Support</a>

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try these steps and see if they improve the performence of your Operating System :
http://www.techdrivein.com/2013/03/4-simple-tweaks-to-improve-unity-performance-ubuntu.html